# ElasticSearch | contains search | escape special characters

Tags: elasticsearch, special-characters, contains

I simple want to perform a **contains search** on my data in elasticseach **AND** I want to **ignore** all **special charaters**.

For example if this is my data: **test@test.com**
If I search for **t@t** that should match the data above.

I see a lot of solutions that turn off analyze which disables "contains" searches but give you ability to ignore special characters.

I would like to have **both** conditions: **contains** AND **ingore special character**

Comment: Can you share a sample of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by ignoring special character. You are using @ in your example too. Can you describe it better?